# Firefox crashes after a few minutes while drawing incanvas

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, svg

I'm actually working with canvas in Mozilla Firefox 47.0.1 and my application crashes the browser after a few minutes.
I just draw a radial gradient as a background and display an SVG image.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/K1eq8wjq

The problem doesn't occur on Google Chrome.

Comment: report it to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) with a testcase

Comment: By crash what do you mean. Does it kill the tab? Whole browser? or just the page stops rendering?

Comment: The whole browser closes and it ask me to send a report (what I've already done)

Comment: My best guess and the only thing I can see that you are doing wrong (well could cause a crash wrong) is that you are adding 2 colour stops to the gradient every time you render the background. Adding a colour stop does not overwrite the previous one, at some stage that will run out of memory. FF just throws a generic error and would stop your rendering.

Comment: Oh to fix, add the colour stops when you create the gradient. if you need to set the colour every frame, then create a new gradient every frame.